# Persistent thread style OpenCL implementation is very slow

Tags: multithreading, opencl

I came across the persistent thread (PT) style implementation for non-homogeneous work distribution and wrote a simple kernel to compare the computation time with a kernel doing the same computations the usual way. But my test implementation is about 6 times slower than the ordinary implementation even without the overhead for sorting the buffer to get corresponding operations of 32. Is this a reasonable slowdown or am I overlooking something? I launched the PT kernel with global_work_size = local_work_size = CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, which is 512. If I chose less, than obviously it gets even slower.

This is the ordinary kernel:

```
__kernel void myKernel(const __global int* buffer)
{
    int myIndex = get_local_id(0);
    doSomeComputations(buffer[myIndex]); //just many adds and mults, no conditionals
}
```

And this is the PT style kernel:

```
__constant int finalIndex = 655360;

__kernel void myKernel(const __global int* buffer)
{
    __local volatile int nextIndex;
    if (get_local_id(0) == 0)
        nextIndex = 0;
    mem_fence(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    int myIndex;
    while(true){
        // get next index
        myIndex = nextIndex + get_local_id(0);
        if (myIndex > finalIndex)
            return;

        if ( get_local_id(0) == 0)
            nextIndex += 512;
        mem_fence(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        doSomeComputations(buffer[myIndex]); //same computations as above
    }
}
```

I thought both implementations should take about the same time. Why is the PT style implementation so much slower? Thank you in advance.

------------Edited below this line-------------

So just to be clear. This kernel launched with global_work_size=655360 and local_work_size=512

```
__kernel void myKernel()
{
    int myIndex = get_local_id(0);
    volatile float result;
    float4 test = float4(1.1f);
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        test = (test*test + test*test)/2.0;

    result = test.x;
}
```

runs 6 times faster than this kernel launched with global_work_size=512 and local_work_size=512

```
__kernel void myKernel()
{
    for(size_t idx = 0; idx < 655360; idx += get_local_size(0))
    {
        volatile float result;
        float4 test = float4(1.1f);
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
            test = (test*test + test*test)/2.0;

        result = test.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `barrier(CLK_MEM_FENCE);` inside `while(true)` loop. Unless you do have one inside `doSomeComputations()`.

Comment: Thx, I changed it, but it's still 6x slower.

Comment: does your last example perform differently when you change it to:  for(size_t idx = get_local_id(0); ...)   ?

Comment: no it doesn't change the performance

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce your second kernel to just this:

```
__kernel void myKernel(const __global int* buffer)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 655360; x += get_local_size(0))
        doSomeComputations(buffer[x+get_local_id(0)]);
}
```

---

**Update**: added summary of the below conversation

First kernel (global_work_size=655360 and local_work_size=512) will be split into 655360/512 = 1280 work groups which will fully utilize the GPU. The second kernel (global_work_size=512 and local_work_size=512) will utilize just one computing unit which explains why the first one runs faster.

More details about persistent threads in GPU: [persistent-threads-in-opencl-and-cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821029/persistent-threads-in-opencl-and-cuda).

Comment: Thx for the comment, but I tried it out and it actually gives me the same slowdown as the PT style implementation. Maybe can you explain why it should improve the performance? Btw I'm using a Intel Iris 5200...

Comment: In that case you need to show what's in `doSomeComputations()`.

Comment: Just some random computations to keep the machine busy. Im using exactly 1000 iterations in a for loop where I multiply and add float4 vectors initialized with all 1.1f.
I also thought it would improve the performance but it doesn't in practice.

Comment: OK, now I see what's the problem. You don't do the same in both kernels. First kernel uses first 512 elements from the buffer, second one uses 655360 elements which is obviously slower.

Comment: No the first kernel is launched with global_work_size = 655360. Otherwise it would be about 1000 times slower. local_work_size is also 512. Sry for missing this information.

Comment: OK so that explains why first one is faster. First kernel will be split into 655360/512 work groups and all computing units will be utilized, In second kernel only one computing unit is being used (global_work_size = local_work_size).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you also tell me how I can utilize all computing units with a persistent thread implementation?

Comment: [persistent-threads-in-opencl-and-cuda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821029/persistent-threads-in-opencl-and-cuda)

Comment: If you update your answer to reflect the conversation, I'd be glad to +1 it.